# C# form doesn't close on FormClosing event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, formclosing

After I added the following code to my code-behind, my form doesn't get closed.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    MyThreadingObj.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What is kind of object is obj that you are disposing ?

Comment: Wrap the dispose in a try/catch, and show or log any exception you get - that might give you a hint. And echoing what @Web is saying: why are you disposing whatever `obj` is at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like adding the above code prevents your `Form` from closing.  If so then the most likely cause is that the `MyTHreadingObj.Dispose()` statement is throwing an exception.  Try wrapping the statement in a try/catch and seeing if this is the case

```
try {
  MyThreadingObj.Dispose();
} catch ( Exception e ) { 
  Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {            
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
            if (PreClosingConfirmation() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Dispose(true);
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        private DialogResult PreClosingConfirmation()
        {
            DialogResult res = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(" Do you want to quit?          ", "Quit...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            return res;
        }
```